# Como fazer um left join usando uma condição where?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Eu tenho duas tabelas:

```
category
--------
id | nome | imagem

user_follow_category
--------------------
id | from | to | date
```

Nota: o relacionamento das duas tabela se dá pela `category.id` e pela `user_follow_category.to`.

O que pretendo é: selecionar todas as categorias (tabela `category`), mas identifique as que estão a ser seguidas pelo usuário "x" na tabela `user_follow_category`.

Esta é a minha query:

```
SELECT c.id, nome, image, u.id AS follow
FROM category AS c LEFT JOIN user_follow_category as u ON c.id = u.to
WHERE u.from = 74
```

**Atualização**

tabela category

```
id    nome       imagem (que ilustra a categoria na App)
1     futebol    futebol.jpg
2     tenis      tenis.jpg
3     box        box.jpg
```

tabela user_follow_category

```
id     from (id do usuário)     to (id da categoria)
1       74                         2
2       74                         1
3       62                         3
```

Desejo obter o seguinte (quais categorias o usuário "74" segue?), algo como:

```
id    nome     segue (ou alguma outra representação)
1     futebol    sim
2     tenis      sim
3     box        nao
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow Mario. Primeiro qual o sistema de base de dados que usa? MySQL, SQLServer? Segundo qual é o seu problema?

Comment: Obrigado. Utilizo o MySql. O meu problema é não consigo recuperar todas os dados da tabela "category" e identificar quais dados estão na tabela "user_follow_category", mas que pertencem ao utilizador "x".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é que a cláusula `WHERE` elimina as linhas que não possuem o usuário especificado. Para resolver isso, mova a condição desejada (usuário "x") para a cláusula `ON`:

```
SELECT c.id, nome, imagem, u.id AS follow
FROM category AS c LEFT JOIN user_follow_category as u 
    ON c.id = u.to AND u.`from` = 74;
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/678711/8). Fonte: [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752507/520779).

Isso vai retornar o id da relação se alguma existir, ou `NULL`caso nenhuma exista. Para uma representação mais próxima do que você pede, pode-se usar `CASE` para testar se a coluna `u.id` é nula ou não:

```
SELECT c.id, nome, imagem, 
    case when isnull(u.id) then "não" else "sim" end AS follow
FROM category AS c LEFT JOIN user_follow_category as u 
    ON c.id = u.to AND u.`from` = 74;
```

[Exemplo atualizado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/678711/10).

Comment: Pó cara, muito obrigado. É exatamente isso que eu preciso. Valeu mesmo mgibsonbr. Tenho de estudar mais Sql.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente a query abaixo:

```
SELECT c.id, c.nome, c.image, u.id AS follow, IF(u.id, 'Sim', 'Não') as segue FROM category c 
LEFT JOIN (user_follow_category u) ON (c.id = u.to)
WHERE u.from = 74
```

Note que talvez seja c.imagem como sua tabela, pois segui os campos de acordo com sua query.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso seja o que precisa:

```
Select * from category a,user_follow_category b where a.id=b.to
```

Comment: Isso vai retornar só as categorias que possuem usuários seguindo, e qualquer usuário, não um específico (i.e. a mesma categoria pode vir várias vezes). Não me parece ser o que o AP quer, mas a pergunta não está muito clara até o momento.

Comment: Ele pode adicionar um select distinct nome... que desta forma trará somente os registros exclusivos.

Comment: Assim não funciona. Irei tornar o problema mais claro. Obrigado.

Comment: Ainda assim se uma categoria não tiver usuário seguindo ela não vai ser incluída no retorno. Pelo que entendi, a ideia é retornar *todas* as categorias - de modo que um *outer join* me parece realmente ser o caminho certo.

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu preciso @mgibsonbr. Mas precisa ser de algum usuário específico.